# Access array elements of dynamic arrayname

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, dynamic, each

I've got a lot of modules with checkboxes which I want to check, using an array.
There are 3 packages with several modules. I generated a dropdown with the package names. After I choose a package, the checkboxes should get checked.

But I have a problem with the generated array name. I can't access it.

```
$("#package").change(function () {
    var starter = ["module1", "module2", "module3"];
    var advanced = ["module1", "module2", "module3", "module4", "module5"];
    var everything = ["module1", "module2", "module3", "module4", "module5", "module6", "module7"];    

    var contract = $('#package').val().toLowerCase();
    var arname = {};

    $.each(arname[contract], function( index, name ){
      $( "#module_" + name).prop('checked', true);  
    });     
});
```

How can I choose the array name, depending on the value of the dropdown #package?

Comment: so, contract will be either `starter`, `advanced` or `everything`?

Comment: yes. one of those 3 names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rearrange your code slightly, like this

```
$("#package").change(function () {
    var arname = {
        starter: ["module1", "module2", "module3"],
        advanced: ["module1", "module2", "module3", "module4", "module5"],
        everything: ["module1", "module2", "module3", "module4", "module5", "module6", "module7"]
    }
    var contract = $('#package').val().toLowerCase();

    $.each(arname[contract], function( index, name ){
      $( "#module_" + name).prop('checked', true);  
    });     
});
```

which makes an object, arname, with properties `starter`, `advanced`, and `everything`

you can access those exactly like your original code

Comment: Or in ES2015+, using a `Map`.

Comment: Please *explain* rather than just posting code. **Before** posting the answer, not later as an edit.

Comment: well, looking at the original code, I assumed he was so close he didn't need too much explanation

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - you should post an ES2015+ answer - I'd be interested in why *map* is a better alternative

Comment: I'm not sure it *is* better in this case. The main advantages `Map` has over using an object are: 1. No potential conflict with inherited properties (but that can be mitigated using `Object.create(null)` to create the object), and 2. Keys can be things other than strings. In this case, there's no possibility of conflict, and the keys are strings, so... So `Map` is an alternative, but I'm not arguing that it's *better*.